Categorical General Relativity

What are some good references for GR from a categorical point of view?

This is essentially just a big-list reference request.
I'm aware that the subject exists and can do some basic sleuthing to find articles like Gaio and Rizzuti's , but hope to communally compile a comprehensive list here. Any pointers are appreciated.

Are you expecting this to be different from asking about differential geometry more generally from a categorical point of view?

@JamesEHanson I suppose I'd expect this question to be a subquestion of that one; answers to this question would probably be acceptable there (with maybe more discussion of physics related concerns in these answers). I think this is broad enough alone to justify a separate question based on the references in the above article, but if the community disagrees or feels it is a duplicate of e.g. this one I am fine deleting it.

@JamesEHanson Perhaps an apt anaolgy is categorical QM (a pretty well developed subject as of 2008) vs. categorical linear algebra, a largely unexplored topic as of 2023. Hopefully there are more detailed and well-developed answers to this subquestion.

I'm not aware of a single canonical field which unambiguously deserves the name "categorical general relativity", but you might like some of the references here. I was also a fan of this note -- I've been told that the main result there was a rediscovery of something well-known, but regrettably I don't remember the "correct" attribution.
